# Using sed to remove digits and white space from a string

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to remove the first occurence of digit(s), the dot, the second occurence of digit(s) **and the space before the word**.

I have come up with this regex:

```
sed 's/^[0-9]\+.[0-9]\+\s//' input.txt > output.txt
```

Text sample:

```
2.14 Italien
2.15 Japonais
```

My regex does not work unfortunately. There is a problem with the `\s` but I can't pinpoint what it is...

Can anyone help?

**edit**: The problem is that I need to remove the first space only as some text contain spaces as you can see below:

```
3.15 Chichewa
3.16 Chimane
3.17 Cinghalais
3.18 Créole de Guinée-Bissau
```

Comment: Do you actually just want to get the second column?

Comment: Seems to work as intended with GNU Sed 4.2.1. Perhaps putting the character class in "range" brackets would help? such as: `[\s]\+` Also, the dot has special meaning when not escaped, you may want to look out for that.

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин How can this work with a plain GNU `sed` call when the OP uses ERE metacharacters (`+`), and extended RE aren't enabled by default?

Comment: @slhck: Those are GNU extensions. If you escape the plus, you don't need the `-r` switch; and to make it more confusing, you cannot escape the plus with `sed -r`. `\s` works as well. Both stop working with the `--posix` switch.

Comment: Not sure, the /usr/share/doc/sed-4.2.1-r1/NEWS.bz2 (Gentoo) file kind-of suggests that the --posix option is required for the "standard" behavior, although the manual does say `-r` is required for extended regexps to work...

Comment: @Dennis Ah, I see. Never used the GNU tools that much. They certainly don't make it easy :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The command you're using should work as-is with GNU `sed`. But with BSD `sed`, which for example comes with OS X, it won't.

- If you're trying to use [Extended Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Extended_Regular_Expressions) – which support the `+` metacharacter – you need to explicitly enable them. For BSD `sed` you do this with `sed -E`, and for GNU `sed` with `sed -r`.

  The `\+` alone *does* with GNU `sed` when EREs are not enabled, but this is less portable.
- You're using the Perl-like `\s`, which doesn't exist for both Basic and Extended Regular Expressions. Regular `sed` doesn't support Perl regular expressions though. GNU `sed` does support the `\s` – but it'd be more portable to simply add the space to your regular expression.
- Finally, your `.` matches one character, so your regex would even match any character in that place, not just a dot. Use `\.` to properly escape it.

So, a solution would be, for GNU `sed`:

```
$ echo "2.12 blah" | sed -r 's/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ //'
blah
```

Or for BSD `sed`:

```
$ echo "2.12 blah" | sed -E 's/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ //'
blah
```

This way you don't need a different regex for different versions of `sed`. With your example:

```
$ cat test
3.15 Chichewa
3.16 Chimane
3.17 Cinghalais
3.18 Créole de Guinée-Bissau

$ sed -r 's/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ //' test
Chichewa
Chimane
Cinghalais
Créole de Guinée-Bissau
```

---

If the *real* problem is that you want to get the second column of a whitespace-delimited file, then you're going about this the wrong way. Either use `awk`, like @Srdjan Grubor says, or use `cut`:

```
$ echo "2.12 foo bar baz" | cut -d' ' -f2-
foo bar baz
```

The `-f2-` specifies the second and all following columns, so this will basically take the first space as the separator and output the rest.

Comment: I run GNU sed and have tried the -r switch as follows: `sed -r 's/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ //' input.txt > out.txt` to no avail.

Comment: Hi slhck: Thanks for the detailed reply. FYI, I use Ubuntu and GNU sed.

Comment: I've tested all of the examples, also with GNU `sed`. What specifically doesn't work? What result do you get? The most straightforward solution in your example would be `cut -d' ' -f2-` though.

Comment: Strange... Well I use Ubuntu with Gnu sed. And none of the examples work as expected on this data set: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Zqz9tyY7). I just get the input file in output...

Comment: `cut -d' ' -f2- in.txt > out.txt` this does not work either...

Comment: Your input is not formatted as you said it was. Please check that more thoroughly: After the numbers, you have a `U+00C2 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX` and then a `U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE`, not just a single whitespace. A `sed -r 's/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ //' input` should do, if you copy whatever is the space between your numbers and the string into the actual command.

Comment: Thanks slhck: that was actually the problem... I don't know what tool you used in order to figure out that was not a single whitespace?

Comment: My vim didn't properly support the characters when I copied them to my machine. I used a Unicode identifier online to look up the values :)

Comment: The POSIX-y equivalent for perl's `\s` is `[[:space:]]`

Answer (score 7):

Why not use awk?

```
cat  input.txt | awk '{print $2}' > output.txt
```

Comment: Hi Srdjan: Thanks for your reply. I have edited my post to further specify my problem.

Comment: See my comment to slhck. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

If the only thing is to drop everything upto and including the first space then this suffices

```
sed -e 's/[^ ]* //'
```

Comment: This would work without the digits but not in this case.

Comment: Using this: `sed -r 's/[^ ]//'` on a file with only a leading whitespace produces the desired effect.

Comment: See my comment to slhck. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use grep:

`grep -oP '[a-zA-Z]+$' input.txt > output.txt`

Answer (score 1):

With any sed:

```
sed 's/^[0-9]\{1,\}\.[0-9]\{1,\} //'
```

Or perhaps this might suffice:

```
sed 's/^[0-9.]\{1,\} //' file
```